# Wordpress theme style not overwriting

Tags: css

I want to overwrite the following

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px)
.masthead .top-bar, .masthead .hide-on-mobile {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I am writing the following in style.css in Wordpress to overwrite the above,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px)
body #page .masthead .top-bar {
   visibility : visible;
   display: inline !important;
}
```

I don't understand why it is not overwriting the theme's style

Comment: You forgot the brackets after `@media screen and (max-width: 830px)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot paranthesis in media query declaration.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px){
   body #page .masthead .top-bar {
     visibility : visible;
     display: inline !important;
   }
}
```